# Angularjs - ngModel.$setViewValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my plunker and the code I can't get to work starts on line 32
http://plnkr.co/edit/pmCjQL39BWWowIAgj9hP?p=preview

I am trying to apply an equivalent to markdown filter onto a directive... I created the filter and tested with manually applying the filter and it works that way,, but I should only use the filter conditionally when the type of content on directive is set to markdown.

I am trying to accomplish this by updating ng-model >>> `ngModel.$setViewValue(html)` but I am getting an error
ngModel.$setViewValue is not a function.. which makes me thing that the controller is not recognized although it is required by the directive.

**Here is a working controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('testOne', ["ngResource", "ngSanitize"]);

app.controller('testOneCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.product = {
    id:12,
    name:'Cotton T-Shirt, 2000',
    description:'### markdown\n - list item 1\n - list item 2',
    price:29.99
};

}); 

app.directive("myText", function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    require: "?ngModel",
    scope:{
        css: "@class", type: "@type"
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {},
    templateUrl: "template.html",
    compile: function(elm, attrs, ngModel){

            var expFn = $parse(attrs.contentType + '.' + attrs.value);
            return function(scope,elm,attrs){
                scope.$parent.$watch(expFn, function(val){
                    scope.exp = { val: val };

                if ( attrs.type == 'markdown'){
                    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
                        var html = converter.makeHtml(val);
                        //scope.exp.val = html;

                        ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
                        ngModel.$render();
                }

                })

                scope.$watch('exp.val', function(val){
                    expFn.assign(scope.$parent, val)
                })
            }
    }
}
})
```

This is a filter for markdown which works when applied.. (I would consider using the filter if I could figure out the way to conditionally apply it to existing directive but I'd rather do it with ng-model)

```
/*
app.filter('markdown', function ($sce) {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return function (value) {
        var html = converter.makeHtml(value || '');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
   };
});
*/
```

Here is the directive template

```
<div ng-class="{{css}}"
        ng-click="view = !view" 
        ng-bind-html="exp.val">
</div>


<div>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="30" ng-model="exp.val"></textarea>
</div>
```

This is the directive in use:

```
    <mb-text ng-cloak 
        type="markdown"
        content-type="product"
        value="description"
        class="test-one-text-2">
    </mb-text>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why `ngModel` is empty?

- When using `require` on a directive the controller is passed as **the 4th argument to the linking function**. In you code you try to reference it as an argument of the compile function. The controller is only instantiated before the linking phase so it could never be passed into the compile function anyway.
- The bigger issue is that `require` can only get a controller of the same element (`{ require: 'ngModel' }`), or parent elements (`{ require: '^ngmodel' }` ). But you need to reference a controller from a child element (within the template).

#### How to get `ngModel`?

Do not use require at all as you cannot get child element's controller with it.

From [angular.element docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element):

> #### jQuery/jqLite Extras
>
> **controller(name)** - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent. By default retrieves controller associated with the ngController directive. If name is provided as camelCase directive name, then the controller for this directive will be retrieved (e.g. 'ngModel').

Inside the linking function you can get the hold of the controller like so:

```
 var ngModel = elm.find('textarea').controller('ngModel');
```

---

### I fixed your directive:

here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xFpK7yIYZtdgGNU5K2UR?p=preview

**template:**

```
<div ng-class="{{css}}" ng-bind-html="exp.preview"> </div>
    
<div>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="30" ng-model="exp.val"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive("myText", function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "template.html",
    scope: {
      css: "@class",
      type: "@type"
    },
    compile: function(elm, attrs) {

      var expFn = $parse(attrs.contentType + '.' + attrs.value);
      
      return function(scope, elm, attrs) {

        scope.exp = {
          val: '',
          preview: null
        };

        if (attrs.type == 'markdown') {
          var converter = new Showdown.converter();

          var updatePreview = function(val) {
            scope.exp.preview = converter.makeHtml(val);
            return val;
          };

          var ngModel = elm.find('textarea').controller('ngModel');
          ngModel.$formatters.push(updatePreview);
          ngModel.$parsers.push(updatePreview);
        }

        scope.$parent.$watch(expFn, function(val) {
          scope.exp.val = val;
        });

        scope.$watch('exp.val', function(val) {
          expFn.assign(scope.$parent, val);
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: The problem I have is that as it seems the linking function does not fire when I use compile

Comment: Ahh,, compile has to return link function... let me try and do this

Comment: When the type attribute value is not "markdown" the directive would have to parse only HTML and ignore markdown:) This is excellent btw, thank you! In the real case scenario I am also enclosing  the textarea and it's html wrapper into ng-if directive that wipes out the scope (which is the reason I use object on the scope.exp.val)

Comment: if you remove ng-if the scope is there,, correctly,, if you keep it it creates the child scope

Comment: thank you. I worked out the condition and it is ok now. It is the ng-if creating a new scope that is still the problem. All else works great.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could pull the controller off any element in the dom--nice! You can also get a reference to a child controller by giving the parent a controller, requiring the parent controller in the child directive, and assigning the child controller to a property on the parent controller in the child post-link that the parent can use in its post-link function. Can't tell which one is less roundabout. :)

Comment: @ Ilan Frumer , here scope is isolated. so what does scope.$parent mean ?

Comment: @MukundKumar even an isolated scope has a parent because all scopes has a parent (with one exception $rootScope). the fact that it is isolated only means it will not inherit from it's parent through javascript's prototype chain but all other child scopes functionality (emit, broadcast, destroy, digest etc.) is the same. When angular compiles a DOM fraction it creates the scope hierarchy as declared in all directives scope definition that are found during the iteration down the DOM.